# Xorg high cpu usage when wireless connection is active

Tags: 14.04, wireless, networking, xorg, realtek

I use Xubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit (3.13.0-43-generic) on a low-end notebook (AMD C-70, 2GB RAM, RTL8188EE) and a router D-Link DSL-2640B.

The wireless connection looks fine, but it is impossible to use the notebook due to slowness.

I changed the video driver (opensource / AMD), but did not solve the problem.

I've tried to use a [modified network driver](http://github.com/FreedomBen/rtl8188ce-linux-driver), but the problem still persists.

Does anyone know any way to solve this problem?

Comment: For me, it's a problem with Realtek rtl8723ae driver.